# plot multiple arrows between scatter points

Tags: python, matplotlib, arrow-functions

I'm trying to plot multiple arrows between two sets of scatter points. Plotting a line is easy enough with `ax.plot`. But I'm trying to implement an arrow instead of a line. The arrows don't appear to be aligning between the points.

So if the line plot is initialised below, it works fine. But the quiver plot does not plot alone  the same lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-50,50,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x1 = df['A']
y1 = df['B']

x2 = df['C']
y2 = df['D']

AB = plt.scatter(x1, y1, c = 'blue', marker = 'o', s = 10, zorder = 3)
CD = plt.scatter(x2, y2, c = 'red', marker = 'o', s = 10, zorder = 2)

# plot line between points
#ax.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2], color = 'black', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.5)

ax.quiver([x1, x2], [y1, y2])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html), see `scale_units` option, you need: `angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1` in `quiver`:

```
AB = ax.scatter(x1, y1, c = 'blue', marker = 'o', s = 10, zorder = 3)
CD = ax.scatter(x2, y2, c = 'red', marker = 'o', s = 10, zorder = 2)

ax.quiver(x1, y1, (x2-x1), (y2-y1), angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]